# Firebase database writing in progress all time

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement user authentication in my project. I use createUserWithEmailAndPassword method. The problem is that users are showing up in Firebase tab - "Authentication", but there is no data in realtime database and app is running all the time.

There is any message from Toast function. So program is stucked somewhere in the middle.

```
Log.d("MYT", "registerUser: start");
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        Log.d("MYT", "onComplete: user create");
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            User user = new User(age, name, email);
            Log.d("MYT", "onComplete: user");
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                    .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {         
                            Log.d("MYT", "onComplete: database ");
                            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "User has been registerd successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "User cannot be register", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "User cannot be register", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
```

Here are the rules for Realtime Database :

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": true,  
      ".write": true,
   }
}
```

EDIT :

I left app running for few hours and it appears that everything is working but very slow. Below are logs:

```
2022-10-06 19:57:15.795 8536-8539/com.application.gymnote I/art: Do full code cache collection, code=120KB, data=109KB
2022-10-06 19:57:15.795 8536-8539/com.application.gymnote I/art: Starting a blocking GC JitCodeCache
2022-10-06 19:57:15.795 8536-8539/com.application.gymnote I/art: After code cache collection, code=91KB, data=74KB
2022-10-06 19:57:17.908 8536-8536/com.application.gymnote D/MYT: registerUser: start
2022-10-06 19:57:17.913 8536-8663/com.application.gymnote D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2022-10-06 19:57:17.915 8536-8663/com.application.gymnote W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
2022-10-06 20:01:19.087 8536-8663/com.application.gymnote W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
2022-10-06 20:01:19.369 8536-8663/com.application.gymnote D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( dzi6q1LHUNXzfuNCXUVk4oPDZq93 ).
2022-10-06 20:01:19.370 8536-8663/com.application.gymnote D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying auth state listeners about user ( dzi6q1LHUNXzfuNCXUVk4oPDZq93 ).
2022-10-06 20:01:19.374 8536-8536/com.application.gymnote D/MYT: onComplete: user create
2022-10-06 20:01:19.374 8536-8536/com.application.gymnote D/MYT: onComplete: user
2022-10-06 20:56:18.553 8536-11207/com.application.gymnote W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
2022-10-06 20:56:57.367 8536-11520/com.application.gymnote W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
2022-10-06 21:00:22.521 8536-11207/com.application.gymnote D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( dzi6q1LHUNXzfuNCXUVk4oPDZq93 ).
2022-10-06 21:00:58.499 8536-11520/com.application.gymnote D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( dzi6q1LHUNXzfuNCXUVk4oPDZq93 ).
2022-10-06 21:23:43.697 8536-8536/com.application.gymnote D/MYT: onComplete: database 
2022-10-06 21:23:43.899 8536-8626/com.application.gymnote D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9c78cfc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9c7b0170)
2022-10-06 21:23:43.931 8536-8626/com.application.gymnote D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9c78cfc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9c7b0170)
```

So my question is what is the cause of the program running so slow ?

Comment: Is any of the toast messages displayed? If yes, which one? Besides that, what is location of your database?

Comment: There is any toast message, the serwer is located in US.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Which toast message is displayed?

Comment: There is no message

Comment: None of the `Toast.makeText( ... )` fires?

Comment: No message, progressbar is loading whole time [image](https://ibb.co/FD2yXHv)

Comment: Is your second `onComplete` even triggered?

Comment: not sure, isn't the issue connected with that the 'onComplete' is greyed out ? [image](https://ibb.co/DVMB6qt)

Comment: No, it has nothing to do. Try to add a log statement and see if it is reached.

Comment: here is the image with logs [image](https://ibb.co/k8CKyYN)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code/log messages as text and **not** as an image. We cannot see all the code. Without it, it's hard to help.

Comment: It's edited now

Comment: What is the location of your database?

Comment: Database location: United States (us-central1)